# JavaOS / Run java bytecode faster

Tags: java, operating-system, boot

I'm wondering if there is an OS that can run java bytecode without a Java installation, like a JavaOS (I know there is something called JavaOS, but I don’t think I want that). All I want to do is run one java program on my laptop, and it seems wasteful to run all the processes that are started with linux along with it. I'm thinking that the laptop would boot into it, and immediately start the java code.

Does anything like this exist?

Edit:

I'm looking for performance boosts.

Comment: Closest thing I know is BEA's (err, Oracle's) LiquidVM, but don't know if that's still around.

Comment: Yeah, It looks like that is designed specifically for server software, It seems to me that @Peter's solution is the best I'm going to get... Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take linux and remove all the things you don't want.

However OSes are pretty good at minimizing the impact of programs which don't do much.

Answer (score 0):

Android is made with Java, Android Runtime is used to interpret Java bytecode and most of Android apps are written in Java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).